# getAdapterPosition returns wrong value?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I am trying not to use `ListView` again and I am trying to get familiar with `RecyclerView`.
I have no problem with using `RecyclerView` until I try to use HORIZONTAL `RecyclerView` inside VERTICAL `RecyclerView` and I made a search and found answer here, so thank you.
I also hope to find answer to my question.

I am making a VERTICAL `RecyclerView` with `CardView` as an item with `OnClickListener` to deal with `ViewHolder` clicks, I have no problem on that.
The problem come when trying to make a share button on the `CardView` once clicked a balloon appears using `GreenDroid` Library with three choices `Facebook`, `Twitter` and `Google+` when on of those is clicked I ask for the position of clicked view using `getAdapterPosition` and it returns wrong value all the time.
This is my code ..

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
        OnClickListener {

    private ImageView imgViewItem;
    private TextView textViewTitle;
    private ImageView imgViewShare;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        imgViewItem = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.img_view_item_no_description);
        imgViewItem.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        textViewTitle = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.text_view_title_no_description);

        prepareQuickActionGrid();
        imgViewShare = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.img_view_share_no_description);

        imgViewShare.setOnClickListener(this);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.equals(imgViewShare)) {
            grid.show(v);
        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                    McDonaldsPagerActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.TITLES_TAG, titles);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.IMAGES_TAG, imgs);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.ID_TAG, id);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

and `prepareQuickActionGrid()` ..

```
private void prepareQuickActionGrid() {
        grid = new QuickActionGrid(context);
        grid.addQuickAction(new MyQuickAction(context,
                R.drawable.facebook_50x50, R.string.facebook));
        grid.addQuickAction(new MyQuickAction(context,
                R.drawable.twitter_50x50, R.string.twitter));
        grid.addQuickAction(new MyQuickAction(context,
                R.drawable.g_plus_50x50, R.string.g_plus));
        grid.setOnQuickActionClickListener(new OnQuickActionClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onQuickActionClicked(QuickActionWidget widget,
                    int gridPosition) {
                // the problem is here .. wrong value is returned all the time
                int position = getLayoutPosition();
                Log.d("position", "" + position);
                // wrong position results in wrong title and wrong image
                switch (gridPosition) {
                case 0:
                    share(Constants.FACEBOOK, imgs[position],
                            titles[position]);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    share(Constants.TWITTER, imgs[position],
                            titles[position]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    share(Constants.G_PLUS, imgs[position],
                            titles[position]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I try to use `getAdapterPosition()`, but it also returns wrong value.
What's wrong in my code.
Any suggestions to overcome this problem.

Answer (score -1):

A quick way to fix this problem would be to put the code inside the `onBindViewHolder` method where you have access to the position.

Comment: I try it, but still giving wrong value and I don't know why.Thank you.

Comment: `onBindViewHolder` used to fill the `RecyclerView` items with data, the `position` in this method will be the position of the last filled item not of the clicked item.